# confusion about velocity's beforeEach setUp function in meteor

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, jasmine, meteor-velocity

I'm trying to implement testing on my meteor application using velocity [1] and jasmine [2].
I defined a collection called 'object' (collections/object.js):

```
Objects = new Meteor.Collection('objects');
```

I implemented a set up function (tests/jasmine/server/unit/ObjectSpec.js):

```
describe('Objects', function () {
  'use strict';

  // set up
  beforeEach(function () {

    // 1 - backup all data
    MeteorStubs.install();

    // 2 - delete current 'Objects'-items
    Objects.remove({});

    // 3 - add test data
    Objects.insert({
       someProperty: 'data1'
    });

  });
```

then I do run the actual tests (same file):

```
  // actual tests
  it("should delete a specific object", function () {
    var selector = {someProperty: 'data1'};
    var selectedObject = Objects.findOne(selector);

    // will return 'Expected undefined not to be undefined.'
    expect(selectedObject).not.toBe(undefined);

    Meteor.call('deleteObject', selectedObject, function(error, id) {
        if (error)
            return alert(error.reason);
    });

    expect(Objects.findOne(selector)).toBe(undefined);
  });
```

after, I restore the old application state in the tear down (same file):

```
  // tear down
  afterEach(function () {
    Objects.remove({});
    MeteorStubs.uninstall();
  });
```

Now, when executing the test, velocity throws me:
    Expected undefined not to be undefined.

I wonder, if the data in the 'beforeEach'-Function actually will be inserted and accessible in the actual testing function? Also, I tried using console.log() in the test functions, to show the current data, but it won't be shown in the browser console. Why?

[1] https://atmospherejs.com/velocity/html-reporter

[2] https://atmospherejs.com/sanjo/jasmine

Comment: you should expect it to be null

Comment: @AdamWolski I'm not sure what u mean. However, the variable 'selectedObject' should contain the object created in the 'beforeEach' function.

Comment: but if it's empty findOne returns null, not undefined